# Python 3 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, скрипт

Есть скрипт на питоне, который позволяет проверять баланс аккаунтов для майнинга в телеграм, а позже делать вывод. Но в итоге выдает лишь баланс, а вывода нет. Итог:

```
python3 balance.py
Входим в аккаунт: +79**********
0.00068383
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "balance.py", line 22, in <module>
    Phone = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Сам код:

```
import sqlite3
import time
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon import sync, events
import re
import json


db = sqlite3.connect('Account.db')
cur = db.cursor()

x = 1
m = 0

while(True):
    if x == 23:
        print("Всего добыто:")
        print(m)
        break
    cur.execute(f"SELECT PHONE FROM Account WHERE ID = '{x}'")
    time.sleep(0.4)
    Phone = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
    print("Входим в аккаунт: " + Phone)

    cur.execute(f"SELECT API_ID FROM Account WHERE ID = '{x}'")
    time.sleep(0.4)
    api_id = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
    cur.execute(f"SELECT API_HASH FROM Account WHERE ID = '{x}'")
    time.sleep(0.4)
    api_hash = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
    session = str("anon" + str(x))
    client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()

    dlgs = client.get_dialogs()
    for dlg in dlgs:
        if dlg.title == 'LTC Click Bot':
            tegmo = dlg

    client.send_message('LTC Click Bot', "/balance")
    time.sleep(3)
    msgs = client.get_messages(tegmo, limit=1)

    for mes in msgs:
        str_a = str(mes.message)
        zz = str_a.replace('Available balance: ', '')
        qq = zz.replace(' LTC', '')
        print(qq)
        waitin = float(qq)

    m = m + waitin
    #print(m)
    x = x + 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Метод `cur.fetchone()` вернул None

Comment: А в базе ID строковый или числовой?

Comment: @CrazyElf , вы про это?
ABLE Account (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    PHONE TEXT,
    PASS TEXT,
    API_ID TEXT,
    API_HASH TEXT,
    ACTIVITY TEXT,
    LITECOIN TEXT

Comment: @Artefice Ага, ну раз `ID INTEGER`, тогда скорее всего надо без кавычек выборку по `ID` делать: `WHERE ID = {x}"`

Comment: @CrazyElf , все так же
File "balance.py", line 22, in <module>
    Phone = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @gil9red С чем связана ошибка? Я не особо разбираюсь в Python. Можно расписать?

Comment: @Artefice А если из базы такую выборку делаете - что-то выбирается?

Comment: @Artefice, думаю, sql запрос ничего не вернул, поэтому `cur.fetchone()` возвратил `None`, а когда квадратные скобки были вызваны у `None` это и вызвало ошибку (подробнее в описании https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone). Получайте значение `value = cur.fetchone()`, проверяйте его значение и работайте с валидным. Кст, лучше, запрос отправлять с связанными параметрами, это многое упростит: `cur.execute(f"SELECT PHONE FROM Account WHERE ID = ?", [x])`

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, выбирается